# Unity C# GraphQL Post Request Body Authentication

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphql

I am working on trying to connect to my GraphQL server my developers have setup from within Unity. I have found some scripts to help with this process, however, I am still not able to connect because i need to be logged into the system hosting graphql to be able to query externally, I cannot just use the endpoint url.

My developer has told me to do a POST request to mysystem/login and in the request body add {email: string, password: string}. I have tried a few different things and nothing is working. I have to log into the mysystem/login with email and password, then i will be able to connect to mygraphql endpoint from the code below.--i was assuming this portion would go where I have the //smt authentication notes. Any help on how to setup the post request and where it should be or how it should work would be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SimpleJSON;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace graphQLClient
{
public class GraphQuery : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GraphQuery instance = null;
    [Tooltip("The url of the node endpoint of the graphQL server being queried")]
    public static string url;

    public delegate void QueryComplete();
    public static event QueryComplete onQueryComplete;

    public enum Status { Neutral, Loading, Complete, Error };

    public static Status queryStatus;
    public static string queryReturn;

    string authURL;
    public static string LoginToken;

    public class Query
    {
        public string query;
    }

    public void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        StartCoroutine("PostLogin");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        LoginToken = "";
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, string> variable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public static Dictionary<string, string[]> array = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    // Use this for initialization

    // SMT Authentication to ELP
    // SMT Needed for Authentication---  if (token != null) request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    //In the request body: {email: string, password: string}
    //You’ll either get a 401 with an empty response or 201 with {token: string, user: object}
    IEnumerator PostLogin()
    {
        Debug.Log("Logging in...");
        string authURL = "https://myapp.com/login";
        string loginBody = "{\"email\":\"myemail.com\",\"password\":\"mypassowrd\"}";

        var request = new UnityWebRequest(authURL, "POST");
        byte[] bodyRaw = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(loginBody);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Login error!");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in request.GetResponseHeaders())
            {
                Debug.Log(entry.Value + "=" + entry.Key);
            }

            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Login complete!");
            //Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
            LoginToken = request.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log(LoginToken);
        }
    }

    public static WWW POST(string details)
    {
        //var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
        details = QuerySorter(details);
        Query query = new Query();
        string jsonData = "";
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        query = new Query { query = details };
        jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(query);
        byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonData);
        Dictionary<string, string> postHeader = form.headers;
        //postHeader["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + downloadHandler.Token;
        if (postHeader.ContainsKey("Content-Type"))

            //postHeader["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
            postHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + LoginToken);


        else
            //postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            postHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + LoginToken);


        WWW www = new WWW(url, postData, postHeader);
        instance.StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
        queryStatus = Status.Loading;
        return www;
    }

    static IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW data)
    {
        yield return data; // Wait until the download is done
        if (data.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("There was an error sending request: " + data.error);
            queryStatus = Status.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            queryReturn = data.text;
            queryStatus = Status.Complete;
        }
        onQueryComplete();
    }

    public static string QuerySorter(string query)
    {
        string finalString;
        string[] splitString;
        string[] separators = { "$", "^" };
        splitString = query.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        finalString = splitString[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < splitString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                finalString += splitString[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if (!splitString[i].Contains("[]"))
                {
                    finalString += variable[splitString[i]];
                }
                else
                {
                    finalString += ArraySorter(splitString[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return finalString;
    }

    public static string ArraySorter(string theArray)
    {
        string[] anArray;
        string solution;
        anArray = array[theArray];
        solution = "[";
        foreach (string a in anArray)
        {

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < anArray.Length; i++)
        {
            solution += anArray[i].Trim(new Char[] { '"' });
            if (i < anArray.Length - 1)
                solution += ",";
        }
        solution += "]";
        Debug.Log("This is solution " + solution);
        return solution;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to do a little bit of refactoring so you can chain two POST coroutines together.  It sounds like you need to post to GraphQL once to get the token.  Once you have it, post again with your query with postHeader["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+ firstResponse.Token;

Comment: @LeoBartkus thanks for this--I worked with my devs and was able to get a solution for logging in on the first POST request, see updated code above as you mentioned--I just need some guidance as to where I pass in the postHeader["Authorization"]--assuming the second WWW Post, but any more help would be appreciated--last thing holding me back!!! So close.

Comment: If you have a token, you can add it to the headers around where you add the content-type header.

Comment: @LeoBartkus I still seem to be getting a 401 unauthorized---see updated above--i must be missing something....